# TypeError: Fallback function must be defined as "external"

Tags: fallback-function

function() public payable{

^

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./EIP20Interface.sol";


contract InitialTokenOfferingIncomeFAIR is EIP20Interface {

    uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;

    string public name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    string public symbol;

    uint price = 0.1 ether;

    function ito(
        uint256 _initialAmount,
        string memory _tokenName,
        uint8 _decimalUnits,
        string memory _tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        balances[msg.sender] = _initialAmount;
        totalSupply = _initialAmount;
        name = _tokenName;
        decimals = _decimalUnits;
        symbol = _tokenSymbol;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
        require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance >= _value);
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        if (allowance < MAX_UINT256) {
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        }
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    function() public payable{     *//Fallback problem concerning this function*

        uint toMint = msg.value/price;
        totalSupply += toMint;
        balances[msg.sender]+=toMint;
        emit Transfer(0, msg.sender, toMint);

    }
}
```

Comment: Just change `public` by `external`

Answer (score 2):

The fallback function signature must look something like this:

```
function() external payable { ... }
```

or

```
function() external { ... }
```

A fallback function is used when no function is provided or if the function requested does not exist.  There is no good reason why a contract would need this capability when making internal calls, so for clarity Solidity requires you only use it for `external` calls.

For more, see https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.5/contracts.html#fallback-function